# What's the meaning of "Good thing he has you"?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

Is "good thing he has you" authentic?

Can I rephrase this sentence as the following:

> It's good thing that he has you.

Answer (score 3):

"Good thing he has you!" is slightly less formal and more colloquial than "It's a good thing he has you." Both are grammatical and equivalent in meaning. "It's a good thing that he has you" is grammatical as well, but sounds a bit stilted; it's a bit too correct, and not the sort of thing one would expect to hear from a native speaker.